# SQL: minimum level of rights for activity monitor and server logs

Tags: sql-server-2005

In SQL 2005 and above, If i dont want to give someone sys admin rights how can the person see Activity monitor and sql server logs?

what is the minimum level of rights to see Activity monitor and sql server logs in SQL server?

any help?

regards

Manjot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activity Monitor: VIEW SERVER STATE according to MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175518.aspx

SQL Server Logs: account must be a member of fixed server role 'securityadmin' according to MSDN: ms178326(SQL.90).aspx

With the logs though these are accessible at the file level through Explorer as well, so you will need to restirct access to the log directory on the physical server.